# Exact formula for generating function of all binomial coefficients.

Tags: combinatorics

Let 
$$G(x,y)=\sum_{s,t\ge 0}{s\choose t}x^{t}y^{s}$$

> Find $G(x,y)$

I tried to use the following formula ${n+1\choose k+1}={n\choose k+1}+{n\choose k}$ to extract that function. But i made some mistakes and i hope that you will help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Recall binomial theorem and sum over $t$ first.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $s \geq t$ (otherwise the binomial coefficients are zero) so more explicitly the sum is
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \sum_{s=t}^{\infty} \binom{s}{t} y^s x^t.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use the identity
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \sum_{s=t}^{\infty} \binom{s}{t} y^s =\frac{y^t}{(1-y)^{t+1}}
\end{eqnarray*}
and then sum the geometric plum.

Comment: so the answer is $\frac{1}{1-y-xy}$. Thanks!

Comment: That is exactly what I have written in my notebook $\ddot \smile$